# How to clone different GIT Repo's specific folder while cloning one GIT repo

Tags: git

We have multiple GIT repos and have requirement of including one subdirectory from different repo while cloning the main GIT repo.
Example:
When I clone repo_1 it also should clone repo_2:/src/dev
So, only one clone command will be executed "git clone -b master repo_1." and it also should clone repo_2:/src/dev directory at the same time.

Is this possible to do in GIT?

Answer (score 1):

It is through [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), where `repo1` can reference a specific commit of `repo2`, which will be checked out as a *subdirectory* of `repo1`.
Using a script like [`Reedbeta/git-partial-submodule`](https://github.com/Reedbeta/git-partial-submodule) can help making sure repo2 is using a sparse checkout, in order to deliver only its `src/dev` content instead of the full repository.

What is not possible, as far as I know, is to have both repositories checked out in the same local folder.